# Searching array field in Postgres from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

This query: `select * from test where all_ids && array['Cff203176c6d007c1a5b1111e0978221d', 'Cfef30ccc18809aeb413e94101eac0684', 'Cfe6e67da4edd16cd9f022fee1f11bfdf', 'Cfe5a61f4e6dd546abc8e5d9f84bdc43b'];` works on postgres, where all_ids is text[] data type. Four results are returned.

But when I run it from nodejs app, using pg module, like:

`const { rows, rowCount } = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE all_ids && array[$1]', [ids]);`

I get zero rows back. ids is an array of string with values from above. Is this not enabled in node-postgres?

Comment: Can you turn on log_statement = all, and see what is actually getting sent to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this kind of query works:

```
const { rows, rowCount } = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE all_ids && $1::text[]', [ids]);
```